# how to properly use a while loop's syntax and apply it to this piece of code

Tags: python

```
flag = False

while flag == False:
    
    try:
    
        Num1 = int(input('Please enter a number, '))
        Num2 = int(input('Please enter the function, '))

        Opp = input('Please type what you want to do with the numbers: multiply, subtract to subtract your function from Number or divide to divide Number by your function, ')
        if Opp == 'multiply':
            print(Num1,'times',Num2, 'is',Num1 * Num2)
        elif Opp == 'subtract':
            print(Num1,'minus',Num2,'is',Num1 - Num2)
        else:
            print(Num1,'divided by',Num2,'is',Num1/Num2)
    except:
        flag = True
```

A peer and I had to write this program of entering two numbers and either multiplying dividing or subtracting them but in his program he used two while loops with 'try' and 'except' making the whole program more efficient including verification checks of whether a user enter subtract divide or multiply and asks for a re entry if not put in correct. I also noticed after the else statement that executes whenever anything other than subtract and multiply is typed.

Comment: I recommend to use https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ as a better place for questions like this. And please use correct upper case letters in your title.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Before you post at [codereview.se], be sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *is for*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".  Be sure that the code works correctly; include your unit tests if possible.  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.

Answer (score 1):

Try to ask it to divide `14` by `0`. You will get a `ZeroDivisionError` (an exception), that will get catch by the `except` and thus set your `flag` to True, permitting to exit the loop.

A `while` loop repeats until its condition gets false. Here the condition is `flag == False`. So it repeats while `flag == False` stays, which is to say until you cause an exception that let you enter the `except` branch.

Instead, you could do :

```py
flag = False
while flag == False:
    Num1 = int(input('Please enter a number, '))
    Num2 = int(input('Please enter the function, '))
    Opp = input('Please type what you want to do with the numbers: multiply, subtract to subtract your function from Number or divide to divide Number by your function, or "exit" to exit the program')
    if Opp == 'multiply':
        print(Num1,'times',Num2, 'is',Num1 * Num2)
    elif Opp == 'subtract':
        print(Num1,'minus',Num2,'is',Num1 - Num2)
    elif Opp == 'divide':
        print(Num1,'divided by',Num2,'is',Num1/Num2)
    elif Opp == 'exit':
        flag = True
    else:
        print("i did not understand")
```

Instead of relying on an exception to be raised, the usual way to do it is to let the user tell when to exit. Here I added an `"exit"` choice, that sets `flag` in order to exit the loop.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're using a while loop okay.  The else will run if the other if and elif statements do not.  Is there a question you'd like answered?

Perhaps you'd like to change your last else to an elif check on "divide" and a final else for ending the loop.